# Ajax post not working - Jquery Phonegap Android

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova

Hello everyone and thanx in advance.
I am using Phonegap 2.1.0.
In whitelist everything is accepted..

```
**<access uri="*" subdomains="true" />
<access origin=".*" subdomains="true"/>**
```

I am using this function to call a remote php file from my university web server:

```
var postData = $(this).serialize();             
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://--/smartphone/login.php',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    data: postData,         
                    success: function(data){
                        alert("good");
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert('problem!');
                    }
                });
```

THE php file is just for debug reasons like this:

```
    <?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$sample = array(
    'name'=>'My Name',
    'email'=>'my_email@example.com'
);
echo json_encode($sample);
?>
```

But ajax request is not happening.. in eclipse i keep getting this error when i click submit:

```
JSCallback Error: Request failed with status 0 at file:///android_asset/www/js/cordova-2.1.0.js:3743
```

what is more, I forgot to add, is that I can open the url as a link from the emulator.It works fine.

****html code:****

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
   <title>Smart Greenhouse</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="container">
      <img src="css/images/smart_green_house.png" class="logo" alt="l1ogo" />
      <form id="login_form" class="first_display" >
          <label class="title"> E-mail:</label>
          <input id="1" type="email" class="input" size="45" name="email" />
          <label class="title"> password:</label>
          <input id="2" type="password" class="input" size="45" name="password" />
          <input id="3" class="submit_type" type="submit" value="login" />
      </form>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I have searched I think pretty much the whole web...2 days searching...everything has been tested..
Thanx a lot..

Comment: Is `http://--/smartphone/login.php` a valid URL? It doesn't seem like to me.

Comment: -- stands for the domain..like mydomain.example.com.. I apologize if this is misunderstood..

Comment: Try adding "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" HTTP-header on the PHP side, see if it works.

Comment: onon15. Thanx for the reply..Unfortunately the problem remain..

Comment: Just did some searching and found a number of issues with a similar error and all were related to phonegap 2.1.0, is it possible to try phonegap 2.2.0?

Comment: I just upgrated to Phonegap 2.2.0 and when I click submit i get this error {Falling back on PROMPT mode since _cordovaNative is missing. at cordova2.2.0}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, after 4-5 days searching..something worked out for me..I just added `return false` after the ajax callback. And i changed the code as following:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){       
    if (password_ok==1 && email_ok==1)
            {
                var postData = $(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://mysite.xx.x/smartphone/login.php',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    data: postData,         
                    success: function(data){
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert('error!');
                    }
                });
            }
        else
            {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (email_ok==2)
                {
                $("#1").css("border-color","red");
                $("#1").css("background-color","#FFD8CE");
                }
            if (password_ok==2)
                {
                $("#2").css("border-color","red");
                $("#2").css("background-color","#FFD8CE");
                }
            }
    return false;       
    });
```

Now the only problem is that it does not reset the page when successful..but one step at time...

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1** :You need to include two headers in your php file

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

**Step 2** :And include cdn jquery library in your index page.

**step 3** :use script to post the form successfully

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').submit(function(e) {
            var postData = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'http://www.yoururl/test.php',
                dataType : 'json',
                data : postData,
                success : function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error : function() {
                    alert('error!');
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have tested it in phonegap and it is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason is caused by "Form submission". Where did you put your ajax code?  In the index.js?

The exception you got means "0 == Page is unloading."

In your case, i guess you put your ajax codes in index.js which is in the same page with the form. When you submit the form, browser starts to unload current page and load page with results of form submitting. So your ajax codes get the exception "Page is unloading".

Try not to use Form submission.

Comment: Mark thanx a lot for the try..But i tried both and nothing happened. I know what is the erroe meaning..Could it be something in my androidmanifest.xml file or cordova.plist?

Comment: i think it will never work..i dont know why..neither in localhosts works..i dont know where the problem might be..

Comment: actually, when i remove "form", just let ajax call php directly, it works. for example, you can add your ajax call in deviceready event listner function. And then see the result.